# Operating Cameras on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, pictures

Would it be permissible to take a picture with a  film camera operated mechanically?
If not what would be the melacha involved?

Comment: Based on my limitited understanding of photography there is no action of "writing". One merely opens the aperture and light reacts with previously treated film.

Comment: Most decent film cameras include a light meter, which does have electrical elements. Furthermore, enacting a chemical change is mechalel Shabbat, AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

Making a permanent visual record is generally considered a form of "writing"; this includes film photography.

From http://www.yutorah.com/_materials/Source_Sheet-510279.pdf :

> ר' יצחק וויס, שו"ת מנחת יצחק חלק ג סימן כ
>
> בתשו' קרן לדוד שם, כתב
> בפשיטות לענין המצייר צורה על ידי פאטאגראפיע דחייב משום תולדה דכותב
>
> *Minchat Yitzchak* (Responsa of R. Yitzchak Weiss), 3:20
>
> The *Keren LeDavid* wrote that it is obvious that making a picture by photograph would be a Torah violation as a form of "writing."